# VS Code valid contributes.jsonValidation# fileMatch Pattern

Tags: json, regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VS Code extension, in which, I want all files ending with .xyz to use a particular JSON schema in VS Code extension and for that, I've tried the following combinations under the **contribution** in **package.json**:

```
"jsonValidation": [
            {
                "fileMatch": "/*.xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            },
            {
                "fileMatch": "/.xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            },
            {
                "fileMatch": "*.xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            },
            {
                "fileMatch": ".xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            },
            {
                "fileMatch": "/xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            }
        ]
```

But nothing seems to be working for me. Does anyone has any idea about the correct fileMatch pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer with the help of one of my colleagues. Following worked for me:

```
"jsonValidation": [
            {
                "fileMatch": "/*.xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            },
            {
                "fileMatch": "*.xyz",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/xyz.schema.json"
            },
        ]
```